# Is there a way to get the width and height of a Canvas's inner content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is there a way to get the inner width and height of a canvas based on it's content?

I want to allow the user to write text to a canvas and the user is allowed to pick the font size, font family, etc. Problem is since they have control over the font and the length of text I don't have a way of knowing what to set the width and height of the canvas to.

So is there a way to have the canvas be as big as the content inside it (like the display "inline block" property of CSS) or a way to get the width and height of the inner content of a canvas (in that case I would just adjust the width and height of it after each letter in the text is written)?

Comment: `canvas` doesn't have any 'inner content'.  It's a region of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Position a child element inside the canvas. set the child element css as `position: absolute;` and `width: 100%;` which will take the full size of its container.

Comment: Can you give a code example of this please. I don't understand how an internal element placed inside a canvas tag will determine the canvas's width based on the text drawn on the canvas.

Comment: Unless you mean add an object to the canvas - you cannot place elements inside a canvas and have both display. They are only displayed if the browser does not understand the canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the canvas will contain text with a certain font / font-size, you can use the canvas measureText function. See this snippet from here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d"); ctx.font="30px Arial";
var txt="Hello World"
ctx.fillText("width:" + ctx.measureText(txt).width,10,50)
ctx.fillText(txt,10,100);
```